# C++ error in sort function

Tags: c++

I'm making a student record system for an assignment. When trying to run the program I get the error:

> "error: conversion from '' to non-scalar type 'std::stringstream' requested"

It's coming from the `stringstream key = student[j].getLastName` line. Not sure what is wrong.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "Date.h"
#include "Address.h"
#include "student.h"


using namespace std;

int main(){

    string line;
    ifstream inputFile("studentdata.txt");
    bool keepGoing = true;
    Student *student = new Student[50];
    int i = 0;
    while(!inputFile.eof()){
        getline(inputFile, line);
        student[i].setInfo(line);
        i++;
    }
    int choice;
    cout << "A Heap of Students";
    while(keepGoing){ //This while loop creates the menu and asks for user input
        cout << "What would you like to do?" << endl;
        cout << "1. Print full report." << endl;
        cout << "2. Print simple report." << endl;
        cout << "3. Sort records." << endl;
        cout << "4. Quit" << endl;
        cin >> choice;

        //prints full student report
        if(choice == 1){
            for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++){ //Full print loop
                cout << student[i] << endl;
            }
            cout << endl;
            keepGoing = true;
        }
        //Just first and last name
        else if(choice == 2){
            cout << "First Last" << endl;
            for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++){ //Simple print loop
            cout << student[i].getFirstName() << " " << student[i].getLastName() << endl;
            }
            cout << endl; //formatting
            keepGoing = true;
        }
        //sort function
        else if(choice == 3){
            for(int j = 1; j < 50; j++){
                stringstream key = student[j].getLastName;
                int i = j - 1;
                while(i > 0 && student[i].getLastName > key){
                    student[i+1] = student[i];
                    i = i - 1;
                }
                Student[i + 1] = key;
            }

            for j = 1 to A.length
            key = A[j]
            i = j - 1
            while i > 0 and A[i] > key
            A[i + 1] = A[i]
            i = i - 1
            A[i + 1] = key

            keepGoing = true;
        }
        //quit
        else if(choice == 4){
    cout << "Goodbye!" << endl;
            keepGoing = false;
        }
    }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: `getLastName` seems to be a function, which supposedly return something. Aren't you supposed to *call* this function to get the returned value?

Comment: Can you post your student class?

Comment: Oh, and after you fix the first error, you will get *many* more errors. C++ isn't BASIC you know? Please try to actually *read* the error messages you get, and look at the lines they point to, do the code on those lines look like they should?

Answer (score 1):

When you do `stringstream key = student[j].getLastName`, you try to create a new `stringstream` object copying from `getLastName`. Now, `getLastName` is probably a member function, so the compiler doesn't know how to build a `stringstream` from it.

You probably wanted to initialize a `stringstream` with the *value returned* from your member function, so:

```
stringstream key(student[j].getLastName());
```

Comment: Paolo your solution worked but now I am getting an erro in my while loop for not match for operator> in (student + ((unsigned int) (((unsigned int)i) *  108u)))->Student::getLastName > key. I'm a little lost with this whole thing. I'm quite new with C++

Comment: @Anthony Pretty much the same thing. `getLastName` is a (member) function. When you do `student[i].getLastName > key`, you really don't want to know whether *a function is greater than a string*; you want to know if **the value returned** by your function it is! So, again, add `()` to `getLastName`